# Make install fails macOS Catalina

Tags: macos, opencv, cmake, installation

I am trying to install OpenCV to use in C++ on my macOS Catalina using the tutorial here: https://www.learnopencv.com/install-opencv-4-on-macos/ . However, near the end when I have to run `make install`
I get an error saying

```
Install the project...
-- Install configuration: "RELEASE"
CMake Error at cmake_install.cmake:36 (file):
  file cannot create directory: /installation/OpenCV-/share/licenses/opencv4.
  Maybe need administrative privileges.


make: *** [install] Error 1
```

I tried running as root with: 
`sudo make install`

However I get the same error.

I also tried changing the `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` to another folder I created which I was the owner of, however this did not work either.

What could I do to make the installation successful?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried to create directory `/installation/OpenCV-/share/licenses/opencv4` **manually** (e.g. from command line with `mkdir` command)? Also, component `OpenCV-` in the path looks weird. Probably, it should be `OpenCV-4` instead.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I have made the directory and it gave the same error, also then changing it to OpenCV-4 with the same result. What is odd though is that in the CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX shows `~/installation/OpenCV-master/lib/cmake/opencv4` should I make this directory as well?

Comment: Using `~` in `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` is not good: As far as I know, CMake doesn't treat `~` sign specially. So, when you are trying to install the project under root, `~` is treated as `/root`, not as `/home/<user-name>`. If you pass `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` in the command line, use `$HOME` instead of `~`: this variable will be expanded before CMake will see the parameter.